# Unity - Guidelines for color isolation effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, effect

I would like to highlight two objects in Unity so that they stand out. But instead of actually highlighting them, which I already know how to do, I would instead like to have some kind of color isolation effect, like the one we can see in the picture below :

[image]

However, I really have no idea about how I could acheive this !

Could I use some post processing effects to remove the saturation, expect for a set of objects ?

Should I instead desaturate all the materials of all the objects in the scene and also desaturate the sun color ?

Should I apply to all the other objects in the scene a shader that only renders grayscale colors ?

Comment: I'm not a pro but here's what I would try. I'd set up a second camera that has no post effect. When I want to highlight I let that camera render those objects, while the other camera renders the rest of the scene with a desaturated post effect applied to it.

Comment: I found something that explains better what I mean and even has an example about exactly what you're looking for: https://blog.theknightsofunity.com/using-multiple-unity-cameras-why-this-may-be-important/

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be:
 - Add a desaturate post process to your main camera and set its culling mask to everything(but turn off the effect)
 - Create a second camera, make it a child of the first one (so it keeps the same rotation and position) and set its culling mask to something else (a layer where you will place your highlighted objects)
 - When an object needs to be highlighted, add it to the highlights layer and desaturate the main camera. The object will stay colored because it is rendered by the camera that does not have the desaturation effect.

You'll have to play with the "Clear Flags" option of both cameras to get this to work correctly

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with any of this, but I will have a look and see if it works in my case.

Comment: The keywords are Clear Flags and Layers. By setting Clear Flags you can say to a camera "only render elements that are on this layer". Try googling those terms and I'm sure you'll understand pretty quickly.

Comment: Hmmm it seems like the new light weight render pipeline does not support "camera stacking". I wanted to use that in order to be able to use the shader graph as well. Also the "clear flag" property of the camera seems to be gone in my version of Unity (2019.1).

Answer (score 0):

Still using LWRP Post Processing stack, but I'd add a [Color Grading](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-ColorGrading.html) effect and use that to 'tune' your unwanted colours to grey.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think my question is not very clear. The idea was to isolate some objects from all the other ones by only showing those objects as colored, not fade to gray all undesired colors. But I guess your answer would work if this was what I wanted to do.

Comment: If your objects to highlight are the only objects of that colour in view then this will work.  Otherwise you'll need either a custom shader (for single-pass) or some form of masking (for multi-pass).

Comment: Which really just brings us full-circle to @Jonas' answer... :D